# Jupyter Notebook: Execution on Remote Server: are Files Written to Remote Server?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I want to execute a Jupyter Notebook on a remote server.

If I use this:

```
with open('somefile.txt', 'a') as the_file:
the_file.write('Hello\n')
```

Is the file saved on the local or the remote file system?

Comment: Short answer is: Yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the file will be saved into the remote file system. You can make use of applications like Filezilla if you are using Linux OS or you can use Winscp for windows to retrieve the files.